# Google indexed my website name with a space

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Google has indexed my website name with a space between 2 words. Search intellisense shows my website name with a space between both the words. 

Ex: word1 word2 (Stack Overflow) 

What I want is that both the words should not get separated with a space in search intellisense. 

Ex: word1word2 (StackOverflow)

Comment: While it is not exactly clear what you are talking about, Google will do two things if your domain name appears to be using dictionary terms (using Google's dictionary). It will separate and weight each word of the domain name for search- particularly a keyword match domain result, however, there should not be any issues with the actual domain name for linking.

Comment: It'll appear joined for your URL, It won't appear joined if you've defined that within your Title tag.

Comment: My Title tag consist my domain as jointly only.

Comment: This is a search engine behavior and has nothing to do with anything the website has done. This is normal stuff and nothing to worry about. In fact, it is a good thing. Otherwise, for your domain name to be searched as a whole keyword, you will have to build branding for that term which is not an easy thing to do. There are a lot of signals that have to exist and a significant number of primary and secondary brand preferred searches are required.

Comment: It would be helpful to share the domain name in question

Comment: First, I think if you can show your website address and also the keywords, you will have better answer. And about the space, I think you should check you meta tag ( description ), <title> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done because likely your domain name consists of dictionary terms using Google's dictionary- not an actual dictionary. This is normal and has nothing to do with your website or anything you have done. In fact, this is nothing to fix. It is a good thing!

In this case, your domain name has been broken into two or more recognizable terms and indexed as such with a certain small amount of weight assigned to these terms. You will see search keyword matches against your domain name for these terms.

You should still be able to search for your domain name less the TLD and find your site. It may not be first in the SERPs, but that is okay. Who is searching for your domain name this way? Not too many people without being a preferred and recognized brand.

If you want your entire domain name to be recognized as a brand, there are a lot of signals that have to exist along with a significant number of primary and secondary brand preferred searches.

There are 46 signals (my count) that determine branding and too long for this format to list and explain. You would not need all 46, but a fair number of them to determine a brand. As well, you will need brand preferred searches.

A primary or secondary brand preferred search is something like the following:

> SEO Tutorial MOZ

As the first search (primary) resulting in a SERP listing dominated by MOZ.com.

--or--

> SEO Tutorial
>
> SEO Tutorial MOZ

As the second search (secondary) resulting in a SERP listing dominated by MOZ.com.